# How can I remove rectangle from navigationbottom in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to remove the grey rectangle container from the navigation bottom and remain only the navigation bottom with an icon how I can do that, also I need it to show in front of the Grid view list.
so that when I scroll the bottom of GridView shows under the bottom navigation bar without the grey container that covers it any help?
Here is an image:

[image]

and here is my code:
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Home.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> body = [Home(), Home(), Home(), Home()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: body[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: screenWidth * .155,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth * .024),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
```

`
I want it like this :
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: It would help if you add an image of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Set extendBody param of Scaffold to  true. Doing this change will move your grid elements behind bottomNavigationBar

Code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: body[currentIndex],
      extendBody: true, //TODO: Set to true
...
```

For more details:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar` to transparent
        canvasColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0), 
        // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        textTheme: Theme
            .of(context)
            .textTheme
            .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
    child: ...,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use floatingActionButton so the button will float wherever you scrolled the screen

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: body[currentIndex],
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: screenWidth * .155,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.15),
              blurRadius: 30,
              offset: Offset(0, 10),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
       child: ListView.builder(
      ...
```